# Nginx throws 400 error when client sent duplicate header

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, http-status-code-400

From Client, nginx receives Authorization header twice with different values in same request. Because of this ngnix throws 400 error.

```
http header: "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer token"
2023/08/16 12:13:50 [info] 8200#8864: *746 client sent duplicate header line: "AUTHORIZATION: Basic Another token"
```

How to setup nginx that it will consider AUTHORIZATION header coming with Bearer token and ignore another token ?
I can't remove Authorization header from the application which is setting that header with "Basic Another token".

I tried below approach:

```
 map $http_authorization $modified_auth {
        ~^Bearer\s+(.*)   $1;  # Extract the token
        default           $http_authorization;
 }
```

And in location:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $modified_auth";
```